# join multiple table at once in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have almost more than 10 tables in my database(all tables have same columns). I need to join all them at once. Is there a way? Because I am right now doing manually as shown below (for 2 tables). IN case if I need to do this for more tables, should I do it manually as shown below (for 3 tables)

for 2 tables

```
select cd.*, mi.[open], aar.[open] from [dbo].[calendar_date] cd
inner join [dbo].[table1] mi on cd.[date] = mi.[date]
inner join [dbo].[table2] aar on cd.[date] = aar.[date]
order by [date] desc
```

for 3 tables

```
select cd.*, mi.[open], aar.[open], t3.[open] from [dbo].[calendar_date] cd
inner join [dbo].[table1] mi on cd.[date] = mi.[date]
inner join [dbo].[table2] aar on cd.[date] = aar.[date]
inner join [dbo].[table3] t3 on cd.[date] = t3.[date]
order by [date] desc
```

Comment: "I have almost more than 10 tables in my database(all tables have same columns)." -- Yeah, that sounds more like you have a serious design flaw and should have *only one* table instead... Relational tables aren't spreadsheets.

Comment: Do you want to display the contents of all tables as if it were a single table? Then you should use `UNION`. Or do you only want to display the intersections, i.e. the content for which certain values are the same? Then your approach with an `INNER JOIN` may be the right one.

Comment: This does have the smell of an anti-pattern about it. However if it's literally *all* the tables in the database, or all the tables with the same naming convention, you could construct a dynamic-sql query to build the main query for you, which will always then cope with new table additions.